# Ubuntu 14.04 - the pepflashplugin-installer is trying to get additional packages

Tags: flash

After I successfully installed Adobe Flash Player, after some difficulties, Ubuntu 14.04 the `pepflashplugin-installer` is constantly trying to get and install further data.

[image]

I am enclosing the pop-up, but it is in Danish so basically it says that:
The `pepflashplugin-installer` is trying to get further data after the package installation, but the data could not be found, or the data could not be processed. The installer will try again later, or you can try again now.

I can now close the pop-up, or try again. How do I stop this request from popping up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The`pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package is deprecated.

Please enable the Partners repository if you haven't done that already. Then, in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Given the OP's problem, I added the command for removing the problematic package.